# Inherit audit columns and triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger, delete, audit

## Background

I have a database with dozens of tables, some of which should have audit columns.

## Problem

I'd like to avoid the drudgery of creating audit columns manually, and write the `update` and `delete` triggers once.

## Code

There are several different pieces of code that must come together.

### Audit Table

The following code creates an audit table and city table:

```
CREATE TABLE audit (
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT ('now'::text)::timestamp with time zone,
  deleted timestamp with time zone,
  updated timestamp with time zone
);
```

### Example Table

A simple table to serve as an example of the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE city (
  name       text,
  population real,
  altitude   int
);
```

### Parent Table Trigger

The following code creates a database trigger and a delete prevention rule on the audit table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION audit_delete() RETURNS trigger AS
$audit_delete$
BEGIN
  OLD.deleted := current_timestamp;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$audit_delete$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER audit_delete BEFORE DELETE ON audit
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_delete();
```

### Adding Columns

Inheritance requires columns in the child table to match the parent table and must be created manually. Such as:

```
for $name in (SELECT list of tables); do
  ALTER TABLE $name ADD COLUMN
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT ('now'::text)::timestamp with time zone;
  ALTER TABLE $name ADD COLUMN
    deleted timestamp with time zone;
  ALTER TABLE $name ADD COLUMN
    updated timestamp with time zone;
done
```

There's probably a way to detect and auto-add the missing columns using the information schema.

### Establish Inheritance Hierarchy

The following code applies the inheritance to the given table:

```
ALTER TABLE city INHERIT audit;
```

### Insert Data

Add some data into the database:

```
INSERT INTO city ('Vancouver', 603502, 10 );
INSERT INTO city ('Seattle', 620887, 10 );
INSERT INTO city ('La Rinconada', 30000, 5100 );
INSERT INTO city ('Jericho', 20300, -260 );
```

### Delete Data

Remove some data:

```
DELETE FROM city WHERE name = 'Jericho';
```

At this point, I was expecting the `deleted` column to contain the date for the value of "Jericho". Instead, the row as actually removed from the database.

The trigger for `audit_delete()` didn't fire.

## Questions

1. What is the optimal (or usual) way to create a trigger that sets the deleted date on `delete` queries for all tables that inherit from the audit table (using PostgreSQL 9.2)?
2. (Optional) Is this a good use for triggers?

Thank you!

## Related Links

- http://projects.nocternity.net/index.py/en/psql-inheritance
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469116/how-can-i-make-a-trigger-to-use-inheritance-with-that-tables
- http://tapoueh.org/blog/2010/11/24-dynamic-triggers-in-plpgsql.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html
- http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2009-08/msg00026.php
- http://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/100-Log-Table-Changes-in-PostgreSQL-with-tablelog.html

Comment: You can do `ALTER TABLE my_table INHERIT audit`. Furthermore, in a `DELETE` trigger you don't have `NEW`, update the affected row instead with the timestamp and `RETURN NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/DELETE-and-UPDATE-triggers-on-parent-table-of-partioned-table-not-firing-td5683717.html:

> The DELETE and UPDATE triggers need to be on the child tables.  An operation on a child doesn't fire the triggers of the parent.

As such, the following code must also be executed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ${name}_delete BEFORE DELETE ON $name
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_delete();
```

The `audit_delete()` function won't work as written in the question: setting the deleted date is not possible using `OLD.deleted = current_timestamp`. Instead, assuming that the table has a primary key field of `id`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_delete()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE
    'UPDATE ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' SET deleted = current_timestamp WHERE id = ' || OLD.id;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1;
```